# How can I have Firefox notifications bring me to the instance of Firefox that generated the notification?

Tags: notifications, spaces, firefox

I'm running multiple instances of Firefox using different profiles and on different workspaces/spaces/desktops. I am signed into (a different) Slack workspace on each instance of Firefox.  I would like clicking a Slack notification to bring me to the same instance of Firefox that caused the notification, but it seems right now the OS is surfacing just some version of Firefox (not necessarily the same one).

Comment: Unless the OS can tell the difference, unlikely. If you're just using multiple open commands then it can't.

Comment: I was surprised that this didn't just work out of the box, I guess I would've expected that this was tracked via the pid of the process that sent the message?

I'm launching both instances from the command line.  Is there some extra info I need to pass to the OS to help with hinting?

Comment: macOS just isn't designed to run multiple instances of any app - you have to force it. [The best way to force it is before compile.] It is, therefore, not designed to track which app by PID. It tracks by app signature, similarly to if you have an old & new version of the same app, it will always prefer to launch the new one.

Comment: Chrome can't even do this with with PWA's that are launched as separate apps with their own windows and dock icons.